# Slick 3.0 Using Filters to Query data

Tags: mysql, slick

I have a case class as below:

```
case class PowerPlantFilter(
  powerPlantType: Option[PowerPlantType],
  powerPlantName: Option[String],
  orgName: Option[String],
  page: Int,
  onlyActive: Boolean
)
```

My Table mapping looks like this:

```
class PowerPlantTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[PowerPlantRow](tag, "powerPlant") {
    def id            = column[Int]("powerPlantId", O.PrimaryKey)
    def orgName       = column[String]("orgName")
    def isActive      = column[Boolean]("isActive")
    def minPower      = column[Double]("minPower")
    def maxPower      = column[Double]("maxPower")
    def powerRampRate = column[Option[Double]]("rampRate")
    def rampRateSecs  = column[Option[Long]]("rampRateSecs")
    def powerPlantType= column[PowerPlantType]("powerPlantType")
    def createdAt     = column[DateTime]("createdAt")
    def updatedAt     = column[DateTime]("updatedAt")

    def * = {
      (id, orgName, isActive, minPower, maxPower,
        powerRampRate, rampRateSecs, powerPlantType, createdAt, updatedAt) <>
        (PowerPlantRow.tupled, PowerPlantRow.unapply)
    }
  }
```

I would like to go over the filter and populate dynamic query! Additionally, I would like to use a like statement in my resulting SQL for String types.

So in my case above the orgName in my PowerPlantFilter should be checked for existence and if yes, it should produce a like statement in the resulting SQL!

Here is my first attempt, but obviously this fails!

```
val q4 = all.filter { powerPlantTable =>
    List(
      criteriaPowerPlantType.map(powerPlantTable.powerPlantType === _),
      criteriaOrgName.map(powerPlantTable.orgName like s"%${criteriaOrgName}%") // fails to compile here!
    ).collect({case Some(criteria)  => criteria}).reduceLeftOption(_ && _)
  }
```

Is there something built in Slick to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I arrived at and it works, but not sure if this is efficient:

```
def powerPlantsFor(criteriaPowerPlantType: Option[PowerPlantType], criteriaOrgName: Option[String], onlyActive: Boolean) = {
  val query = for {
    filtered <- all.filter(f =>
      criteriaPowerPlantType.map(d =>
        f.powerPlantType === d).getOrElse(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true)) &&
        criteriaOrgName.map(a =>
          f.orgName like s"%$a%").getOrElse(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true))
    )
  } yield filtered

  query.filter(_.isActive === onlyActive)
}
```

But when I examine the generated SQL query, I see two statements being executed on the database whish is as below:

```
[debug] s.j.J.statement - Preparing statement: select `powerPlantId`, `orgName`, `isActive`, `minPower`, `maxPower`, `rampRate`, `rampRateSecs`, `powerPlantType`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` from `powerPlant` where (true and (`orgName` like '%Organization-%')) and (`isActive` = true) limit 0,5
[debug] s.j.J.statement - Preparing statement: select `powerPlantId`, `orgName`, `isActive`, `minPower`, `maxPower`, `rampRate`, `rampRateSecs`, `powerPlantType`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` from `powerPlant` where `isActive` = true
```

How do I optimize this?